# jQuery Tooltips plugin qtip2 - How to define custom styles likes qtip1?

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I am using the great jquery tooltip plugin qtip 2. Check it out if you have not already.
http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/

Does anyone know how to define your own custom css (tooltip colors, borders, backgrounds, radius, etc)  for the tooltip as opposed to using their predefined tooltip styles?

What I tried:

- I reviewed their style guide but it had nothing on defining your own styles. http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/style/
- Tried their forums but they were down (back up now)
- To create my own tooltip classes and reference them
- To convert over my qtip version 1 style definitions (failed)

If this question helped you, please let me know!

Comment: It took a while but their forum is coming up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just put this in my stylesheet.  Use whatever properties, you need...

```css
.ui-tooltip .ui-tooltip-content,
.ui-tooltip p,
.ui-tooltip ul,
.ui-tooltip li,
.ui-tooltip,
.qtip {
    max-width: 280px;
    min-width: 50px;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 19px;
    text-align: center;
    border-color: #666;
}
```

You could also just create your own by pulling one out of the `jquery.qtip.css` sheet and editing it.  Use `mystyle` the same way you'd one of the predefined qTip2 styles.

```css
/*! mystyle tooltip style */
.ui-tooltip-mystyle .ui-tooltip-titlebar,
.ui-tooltip-mystyle .ui-tooltip-content{
    border-color: #303030;
    color: #f3f3f3;
}
.ui-tooltip-mystyle .ui-tooltip-content{
    background-color: #505050;
}

.ui-tooltip-mystyle .ui-tooltip-titlebar{
    background-color: #404040;
}

.ui-tooltip-mystyle .ui-tooltip-icon{
    border-color: #444;
}

.ui-tooltip-mystyle .ui-tooltip-titlebar .ui-state-hover{
    border-color: #303030;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sparky this definitely worked. I almost had it right I just forgot to call the custom css after the qtip2 css.

Answer (score 3):

I personally have 5 themes to my site.  I happen to use [jQuery UI's ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to do that. jQuery UI and qTip2 use the same class names.

The only caveat I found was the order in which you included the CSS files. You need to override the qTip2 styles, so simply include the jQuery UI CSS file *after* the qTip2 CSS file.

Doing it this way allows you to pull down updates to qTip2 without having to worry about your custom qTip2 styles being overridden, as well as, giving you a nice GUI to create your theme in.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Scott of making sure you have the order of you css include right.

Comment: No problem =D qTip2 is pretty awesome. I have had it for over a year.  Only one bug that I had Craig fix that had to do with IE6.